Flask - application , api handling bad gateway after request start processing
I have a flask application with the follow build parameters for UWSGI
CMD ["uwsgi", "--socket", "0.0.0.0:8083", "--protocol", "http", "-w", "app:app", "--enable-threads", "--processes", "4", "--threads", "4" ,  "--master"  , "--harakiri" , "120" , "--socket-timeout", "120" , "--lazy-apps"]
i use a thread to listen to a queue and processs requests ,
def start_listener(): listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=listen_to_queue, daemon=True) listener_thread.start() 
when i hit an api on uwsgi build the request just stops processing and gives me a bad gateway error and no logs are reflected after 5 sec (some processsing is done and some are logged ).
when i do the same without the queue listner , i am able to execute the api .
i want the api to continue processing , when one thread is occupied for the queue
